# How to Add Views to the Scroll View in Android?

Tags: android

I create the following code to create the Bar Chart and Pie Chart using Canvas.

Here is my code

```
public class ChartDemo extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

    LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);
    llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    float[] values = { 50, 100, 50, 20, 30, 60, 100, 90 };

    // Bar Chart
    BarGraph BarChart = new BarGraph(this, values);
    llay.addView(BarChart);

    //Pie Chart
    PieChartView Pie = new PieChartView(this, values);
    llay.addView(Pie);

    //sv.addView(llay);

    setContentView(llay);
    //setContentView(sv);
   }
 }
```

The above code show the BarChart only.
I change my code like the following it gives the Black(blank)Screen only.With out no error and exception

```
  public class ChartDemo extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

    LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);
    llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    float[] values = { 50, 100, 50, 20, 30, 60, 100, 90 };

    // Bar Chart
    BarGraph BarChart = new BarGraph(this, values);
    llay.addView(BarChart);

    //Pie Chart
    PieChartView Pie = new PieChartView(this, values);
    llay.addView(Pie);

    sv.addView(llay);

    setContentView(sv);
   }
 }
```

And i create my Chart Views like the following

```
public class PieChartView extends View {

private float[] Values; 

public PieChartView(Context context, float[] Values) {
    super(context);

    this.Values = Values;

}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

               .......
               .........

        }


}
```

I need to add both chart in Single Screen with Scroll View . But i am not able to add Both in the single Activity.How to do this ??

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more what you mean by "not able". DO you get some error or are they not showing up at all / correctly?

Comment: When i add LinearLayout in to a ScrollView i got the Black Screen Only                                                                                                                                              sv.addView(llay);
    
setContentView(sv);

Answer (score 4):

when you add programmatically views to some layout, like LinearLayout or ScrollView (which derives from FrameLayout), you should set layout parameters on your views, something like this (just an example):

```
BarGraph BarChart = new BarGraph(this, values);
// be sure to use correct layout params for your layout
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llp.weight = 1.0f;
BarChart.setLayoutParams(llp);
llay.addView(BarChart);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams flp = new /* ... */;
llay.setLayoutParams(flp);

sv.addView(llay);
```

if you don't set them, they get default ones depending on the layout, and they might do the job or not depending on the added views.
(btw conventionally in Java variables names begin with lower case)